# Can someone see my actual cookie data in encrypted cookie using AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING?

Tags: cookies, encryption, aes, session-cookies

I am planning to store some kind of sensitive data of login user into http cookie. I use AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING with key is 256 bits to encrypt my cookie. My question is there is any chance for someone to see my actual cookie data ( contains some sensitive data ). Anyone does this in the real word where the web application is public access. Is my cookie is 99.99% protected? Thank you!

Comment: Nothing in the whole world is 100% protected

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov: I changed 100% -> 99.99%.

Comment: Note that I would trust a protocol that uses an authentication tag much more than one that prefers 256 bit over 128 bit AES encryption. It shows that the designer at least understands a bit about security.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to see how secure an algorithm is within a specific system. AES / CBC is known to be good for creating confidentiality. But that does not mean that the system is safe. As an example, it may be that padding oracles apply, in which case each plaintext byte can be found by 128 tries on average.

Comment: Reviewing the system security is however off topic on Stackoverflow; if you create a really good description then that could be reviewed on http://security.stackexchange.com however.

Comment: I also add Hmac for encrypted cookie to prevent Padding oracle attacker. Is there any-else known attack?

Comment: @Loc Probably, but it is hard to know without the full protocol. If SSL is not used you could for instance replace a new cookie with an old one. I'll leave it at this, if you don't mind :|

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend you read: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs261-f12/misc/if.html which lays out why simply encrypting your data is insufficient, and you also need authentication.